# MATLAB intlinprog prevent display output

Tags: matlab, output

My current code uses the following function:

```
[x] = intlinprog(coeffs,xint,A,be,[],[],lb,ub);
```

I always end my commands with a semicolumn, but even though once this code line is executed I get the following output:

`LP:    Optimal objective value is %somenumber.`

`Optimal solution found.`

`Intlinprog stopped at the root node because the objective value is within a gap tolerance of the optimal value, options.TolGapRel = someothernumber (the
default value). The intcon variables are integer within tolerance, options.TolInteger = onemorenumber (the default value).`

In the end, it does not display x, therefore I guess the semicolumn works, but my question is: is there a method to prevent Matlab from displaying what reported above?

Comment: This is in the documentation for `intlinprog` and is fairly standard across the Optimization toolbox:  `opts = optimoptions('intlinprog','Display','off');` `intlinprog(coeffs,xint,A,be,[],[],lb,ub,opts);`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see it. Should I remove my question because it is trivial?